# How can I create a repeating element from data received from <iron-ajax>?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
                    <iron-ajax auto
                           url='http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats'
                           handle-as="json"
                           last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>


                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
                    <paper-material class="add-players">
                        <div class="layout horizontal center">
                            <h2>{{item.players.name}}</h2> //NOT SURE WHAT SYNTAX SHOULD BE
                        </div>
                    </paper-material>
                </template>
```

I am using  to return a response from a public API. The problem I have is that the API returns an object and Polymer does not allow us to do a dom-repeat over an object. I am really trying to access an array within that object, is there some way to extract that array from the object returned and do a dom-repeat over that array? If not is there another solution to accessing the response from polymer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `{{response.players}}` instead of `{{response}}` in the `dom-repeat`. Here is a working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>

  <title>paper-scroll-header-panel not working</title>
  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-material/paper-material.html">
  
  
  
  
  <!--<link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">-->
  
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">

<test-elem></test-elem>

<dom-module id="test-elem">
  <template>
   <iron-ajax auto
                           url='http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats'
                           handle-as="json"
                           last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>


                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.players}}">
                    <paper-material class="add-players">
                        <div class="layout horizontal center">
                            <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
                        </div>
                    </paper-material>
                </template>
    </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is : "test-elem"
      });
    </script>
    
</dom-module>
























</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, knew it was something like this. Thank you!